# how to show a message before backward navigation in windows phone 8.1 win RT?

Tags: navigation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, back-button

A have a login page. When user logged in successfully, a home page appears. After exploring the home page, when user will be done he/she will want to exit. So, pressing windows default back button will take them to the login page. I just want to show a message dialoge(It will say whether user is sure about exiting.) when user will press back button for exiting from his/her home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle hardware back key press event handler.

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

private async void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you wish to exit?", "Exit");
    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
    // handle result ....
}
```

Be careful how you handle it though, and make sure to unhook the event handlers you no longer need. You could handle it only in one place and check if there are no entries in back navigation history:

```
if (!Frame.CanGoBack)
{
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you wish to exit?", "Exit");
    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @igrali for your kind response. But whenever i put the MessageDialog in the HardwareButtons_BackPressed, the app suspended while pressing back button. i have the code in git. i am giving the link so that u can see the code and make neccessary changes. [link] (https://github.com/Nafisisty/messagebox)

Comment: @KaziNafisIshtiaqueDhoirjosh please give a link to the exact file where you show the MessageDialog, not the whole repository.

Comment: thanks @igrali for your help. I have solved the problem. Needed some more coding. As I am in beginner level, it takes more time to understand and solve.